# How do I resolve update on codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im Lost Please, How do I resolve the following on CodeIgniter?

**/view/index.php**

```
<form action="<?=base_url() ?>home/update/<?php echo $row->userID; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" ></input>
</form>
```

**/controller/home.php**

```
public function update( $id ) {
    $this->MyModel->updateUser( $id );
}
```

**/model/mymodel.php**

```
function updateUser( $id ) {
    $status = 'actived';  //define here my default rules
    $this->db->where('userID', $id);
    $this->db->update('tableUsers, array('userStatus' => $status));
}
```

**/config/routes.php**

```
$route['home/update/(:any)'] = 'home/update/$1';
```

EveryThings is ready, when I put this for example:

```
http://localhost/project/home/update/5
```

But I want update on same page 'view/index.php'
I dont want redirect other pages. I want capture the input submit or the
action, and update the user in view/index.php

*Thanks*

Comment: Doing all the actions in the same page is a bad practice. You could, however, make all with AJAX and submitting to the pages you already have, but you wouldnt leave the current page. View is for VIEW, update is for UPDATE, create is for CREATING, etc. Don't mess all in the same place. You could do it with JQuery `serialize()` and `ajax()` with an `event.preventDefault()` after the ajax call. In your controller, return with a `200 SUCCESS` header, or a `500 SERVER ERROR` header if there was an error. Optionally show an error message and get it with `JQuery ajax.fail()`

Comment: Really, but I use getBoostrap and when the user click button submit this load a jquery #ToggleMODAL, I want to update userStatus in the same pages, because this $row->usersStatus show in #myModal.

Comment: Well, your modal will show a DIV, and surely the modal accepts a function as parameter. If its the case, load the DIV content via AJAX to your update/5 controller. It will response some HTML code that you can use to display the #modal. If there isnt a function as parameter, dont call modal() directly. Call your custom Javascript function, load the DIV content via AJAX, then call modal() with the HTML you already have.